# How to retain controls values when hitting the back button with AJAX 2.0

Tags: ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Here is a .NET challenge.

I am using AJAX 2.0 to post from page1 to page2; however when I click the browser’s back button
from page2; the  AJAX control does not have the same values as originally posted.

How can I retain/display the values that where originally posted to the page2.???